# Different profiles for Stack Overflow vs Stack Exchange links after account merge

Tags: bug, merge-accounts

Some months ago, I accidentally merged my account with another one I had forgotten that existed by changing the email address (while on Stack Overflow, specifically). Now, I accidentally middle-clicked on the inbox icon (instead of my profile), and got this weird page:

[image]

So, I went to developer tools and...:

[image]

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: A merge will merge all details into the lowest numbered ID. However, each site has its own IDs and you're looking at your Stack Exchange ID... not your SO ID...

Comment: @JonClements So, should I understand that it's working as designed? I see what you mean about the IDs, though, by going to MSE